# Pega ID de uma linha que acabou de ser criada em PHP

Tags: php, sql, web-service, aplicação-web

Eai galera, 
Então
eu estou com um problema que é o seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela **jogadores**, uma tabela **treinos** e uma tabela auxiliar **jogadortreino** (onde irei ver se algum jogador está treinando no momento)
A questão é, como eu posso fazer para que na hora que eu crie um treino, essa tabela auxiliar seja populada com o ID do treino que acabei de criar e o id dos jogadores.
Por exemplo, na minha interface eu seleciono um treino e seleciono jogadores que irao participar, ao clicar no botão "Iniciar treinos" eu quero que, alem de criar uma coluna na tabela **treinos**, com ID auto-increment, quero que crie na tabela **jogadortreino** uma linha com o ID que acabou de ser gerado.
Espero ter ilustrado bem haha.
Em java seria usando o Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS, mas em PHP eu já não manjo. 
Alguem sabe como fazer?

Comment: Qual a extensão usada no PHP para interagir com o DB?

Comment: Quer pegar o último id inserido naquela tabela isso? vc precisa dizer qual API está usando para conexão no banco.

Comment: @Bacco eu estou usando conexão PDO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caso esteja usando a extensão MySQLi:

```
mysqli_query( $con,"INSERT INTO jogadores(nome, idade) VALUES ('Pedro',35)" );
$id = mysqli_insert_id( $con ); // Aqui obtemos o ID do registro inserido
```

Para PDO:

```
$id = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Caso esteja usando a extensão MySQL, o que **[não é recomendado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579)**:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Valeuuu, sabia que era algo simples haha. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: @LuanGabriel por favor marque a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id FROM tabela
```