# Retornar apenas o último registro inserido no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá pessoal estou com um projeto porém tenho que fazer uma consulta e nela retornar o a "última linha" ou último registro inserido no banco de dados.

Comment: se tiver id autoincrement     select id.....order by DESC limit 1

Comment: Se sua tabela tiver um campo tipo "criado em" que seja timestamp `SELECT MAX(criado_em) FROM tabela`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97453/91

Answer (score 2):

Existem duas formas de retornar o último registro de uma tabela no banco de dados mySQL.

Pelo maior valor da chave primária da tabela ou campo ID, por exemplo:
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tabela
Onde a variável ID é a chave primária e tabela é o nome de sua tabela.

Por ordem decrescente de seleção, por exemplo:
SELECT ID FROM tabela ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
Onde a variável ID é a chave primária e tabela é o nome de sua tabela.

Pelo último registro adicionado do comando INSERT, por exemplo:
INSERT INTO tabela (nome) VALUES ($nome)

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
Os comandos devem ser executados juntos, caso contrário LAST_INSERT_ID retornará 0 como resultado.